# Updating a custom CursorAdapter performing a request inside getView fails

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm still not getting exactly how a custom `CursorAdapter` should work, so after hard tries, here is the thing :

1. I implement a listener on a button inside my `getView()`.
2. The listener launches a delete row event.
3. To get to it, I use a singleton database where I can perform request from all classes (The purpose of a singleton actually)
4. I usually update (insert and modify) from the activity class, so I just have to get the new database cursor and re-assign it to a new `CursorAdapter`, that I re-assign itself to the `ListView`.
5. Here it's different : I'm inside the `CursorAdapter` class in the `ListView` method, and I don't know how to update my adapter from the inside.

For people who don't want to read my boring explanations, here is the code of the `getView` :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    convertViewParam = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertViewParam == null) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (type) {

        case TYPE_ADD_NOTE_TOP:
            convertViewParam = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_note_top, null);
            viewHolder.contentNote = (EditText)convertViewParam.findViewById(R.id.add_note_top_id);
            break;
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            convertViewParam = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_note, null);
            viewHolder.delete = (Button)convertViewParam.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            if (deleteMode){
                viewHolder.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                viewHolder.delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            viewHolder.contentNote = (TextView)convertViewParam.findViewById(R.id.note);

            getCursor().moveToPosition(position - 1);
            int currentPosition = getCursor().getPosition();
            Cursor c = getCursor();
            c.moveToPosition(currentPosition);

            ((TextView) viewHolder.contentNote).setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("content_note")));
            int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            viewHolder.delete.setTag(new Integer(rowId));
            viewHolder.contentNote.setTag(new Integer(rowId));

            OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int thePosition = (Integer) v.getTag();

                    int posCurs = notesCursorAdapter.getCursor().getPosition();
                    NoteDataSource.getSingletonObject(context).deleteNote(thePosition, context);
                    notesCursorAdapter.changeCursor(NoteDataSource.getSingletonObject(context).getAllNotes());
                    notesCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            };
            viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(listener);

            break;

        case TYPE_ADD_NOTE_BOTTOM:
            convertViewParam = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_note_bottom, null);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertViewParam.findViewById(R.id.bottomLayout);
            linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            break;
        }
        convertViewParam.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertViewParam.getTag();
        if (viewHolder.contentNote!=null){
            if (viewHolder.contentNote.getTag() == convertViewParam.findViewById(R.id.note)){
                int test = (Integer) viewHolder.delete.getTag();
                System.out.println("current tag " + test);
                String txt = getCursor().getString(getCursor().getColumnIndex("content_note"));
                ((TextView) viewHolder.contentNote).setText(txt);
            }
        }


    }

    return convertViewParam;
}
```

I get the following error when I launch the delete event:

```
03-28 17:51:32.996: E/AndroidRuntime(7115): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
```

If you want more info ask.

I'm looking for a bug fix or an just explanation, thanks.

Comment: Do you need a new cursor or can u reuse the cursor which you pass to the Adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a very well written problem statement. I have had this problem and broke my head over it. Try this.

- In your Adapter make a listener, something like

> ```
> public interface ItemDeletedListener(){
>     public void itemDeleted(int position);
> }
> ```

- create an instance of ItemDeletedListener in your adapter, m_listener.
- Write a setter function, setItemDeletedListener( ItemDeletedListener listener){}
- In your getView(), onClickListener, call  m_listener and pass the position that needs to be deleted.

Now in your Activity, Do the following.

1. Implement the listener, that you created above.
2. In your implementation, do the deletion work and then do a changeCursor() there.

Comment: Sounds like a smart solution, I'll use it as backup if I'm not succeeding in doing slukian solution, because as long as I have misunderstanding, I think my code is wrong. I'll keep in touch. Thanks !

Comment: Slukian's suggestion should work. I was not sure whether u needed a new cursor or not as I was not sure about your implementation. Hence I had asked about it in the comment above.

Comment: I'm trying your solution. I'm almost done, but I get a null pointer exception in the following line : 
   m_listener.itemDeleted(thePosition);
My question is how do I instanciate m_listener (I mean I have to call setItemDeletedListener) but what do I have to put in parameter ?

Comment: In your activity class, ItemDeletedListener yourListener = new ItemDeletedListener(). You'll be asked to implement the itemDeleted(int position) method. Here you handle things the way you normally do in your activity class. Then in your adapter you do yourAdapter.setItemDeletedListener(yourListener). This you must do before setting the adapter in your listview

Comment: You are life saver. Worked perfectly even if it's maybe not the efficient way. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome :) If I manage to figure out how to work it without the listener, i'll update you. I actually used this for a more complicated requirement, where I had to load a new cursor into the current adapter.

Comment: (I won't bet my hand, but I think it's actually what I'm doing ==> loading a new Cursor in the adapter, which is describe as good practice. Anyway, I'll work on it for a long time, so same, if I figure out a better solution, I'll update too).

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know on which line you get the exception. First of all one bad thing is that you delete a note from the database based on a position `int` and after that you fetch again all the data and move the position on that cursor on the previous deleted position.

If you have 3 notes(and you show them in the list) in the database and you want to delete the last one this will happen:

- the `thePosition` will be `2`
- you delete the note
- fetch again all the notes from the database (the cursor will have 2 rows now because you deleted one)
- move the cursor to `thePosition` (value 2)
- the cursor has only 2 rows(numbered from 0) and you ask for row with the number 2
- exception

If you want to delete a note then pass as a tag the `_id` for that row and use that to delete the note:

```
Cursor c = getCursor();
c.moveToPosition(position); 
long rowId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
viewHolder.delete.setTag(new Long(rowId));
```

Then in the `onClick()` method use that to delete the note and stop messing with the `moveToPosition()` on the cursor.

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND My code should replace `viewHolder.delete.setTag(new Integer(currentPosition));` in the `getView` method, don't put it the `onClick` method. In the `onClick()` method you retrieve the tag: `long theId = (Long) v.getTag();` and use it to delete the note.

Comment: I got it. After some struggle, I have something better, but not decent yet : when I delete, the list is randomly reorganized, and sometimes the row disappear (which is the improvement), without errors. Anyway, I post the new code, but the problem is solved, I'll try to figure it out by myself. Thanks !